# How to add code in Pine Editor to cross check graphs of different timeframe of the same ticker

Tags: pine-script

So far, I have a program that indicates, using arrows, when the price is below Oversold level for the MACD and the Stoch RSI and the RSI OR above Overbought level for the MACD and the Stoch RSI and the RSI. Though there are good entry for buy and sell, there are still a lot of bad entries. I want to add code that will compare the low MACD of the 'D' to the low MACD  of the '1m'. If both of them have low MACD, then the indicator will appear for the 'D'. This will help eliminate most of the false entries. The only problem I am having is that I can't seem to be able to write a code that will cross-check the MACD of the '1m' with the MACD of the 'D'. Please take a look and answer, if possible. Thank you!

```
//@version=4
study(title = "Long_entry", shorttitle = 'long', overlay = true, precision = 6)
//overlay = true to have it on price graph
//overlay = false to have it separately




//user input
rsiLength = 21
rsiOB = 70.00
rsiOS = 50.00

//Check RSI signal
rsi =  rsi(close, rsiLength)
rsi_bear = rsi >= rsiOB
rsi_bull = rsi <= rsiOS


//Input Stoch RSI
smoothK = 3
smoothD = 3
lengthRSI = 21
lengthStoch = 21
src = close
rsi1 = rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = sma(k, smoothD)

stoch_bull = if d > k and d< 30.00 and k<30.00
    true
else if crossunder(d, k) and d< 30.00 and k<30.00
    true

stoch_bear = iff(d< k and k > 80.00 and d > 80.00, true, false)

//Input MACD
fast_length = 12
slow_length = 26
src_macd = close
signal_length = 9
sma_source = false
sma_signal = false
fast_ma = sma_source ? sma(src_macd, fast_length) : ema(src_macd, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source ? sma(src_macd, slow_length) : ema(src_macd, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal ? sma(macd, signal_length) : ema(macd, signal_length)
diff = macd - signal
macd_bull = if macd <= signal and macd < 0 and signal < 0
    true
else if diff < 0.02 and macd <0 and signal < 0
    true
macd_bear = iff(macd >= signal and macd > 0, true, false)

//*Double check with MACD from 1m

//*new_frame_blue = security(syminfo.tickerid, "1m", macd)
//*new_frame_orange = security(syminfo.tickerid, "1m", signal)
//
//*confirm = if(new_frame_blue > 0 and new_frame_orange>0 and new_frame_blue < new_frame_orange)
//*   true

good_entry = rsi_bull and stoch_bull and macd_bull
good_sell = rsi_bear and stoch_bear and macd_bear

//Draw indicator to chart
plotshape(good_entry, style =shape.arrowup, color = color.green, location = location.belowbar, title="Buy signal" )
plotshape(good_sell, style =shape.arrowdown, color = color.white, location = location.abovebar, title="Sell signal" )
```

I have indicated my latest failed code with *